# Make centered LaTeX tabular table using knitr kable

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

The `knitr::kable` with the `latex` format option produces a tabular environment.
For example,

```r
# produces a tabular environment
knitr::kable(head(cars),
             format = 'latex')
```

produces

```latex
\begin{tabular}{r|r}
\hline
speed & dist\\
\hline
4 & 2\\
\hline
4 & 10\\
\hline
7 & 4\\
\hline
7 & 22\\
\hline
8 & 16\\
\hline
9 & 10\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

The table is not centered. If I use `kable_stylying` from `kableExtra`, whose value for the option `position` defaults to `center`, I get a centered floating table, using the LaTeX `table` enviornment.
For example, this

```r
# produces a tabular environment inside a table
knitr::kable(head(cars),
             format = 'latex') %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

produces

```latex
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{r|r}
\hline
speed & dist\\
\hline
4 & 2\\
\hline
4 & 10\\
\hline
7 & 4\\
\hline
7 & 22\\
\hline
8 & 16\\
\hline
9 & 10\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, I just want to make a small, almost inline, table. I do not want it to float. I do not want captions, etc. What I want then is something to produce LaTeX code like this:

```latex
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r|r}
\hline
speed & dist\\
\hline
4 & 2\\
\hline
4 & 10\\
\hline
7 & 4\\
\hline
7 & 22\\
\hline
8 & 16\\
\hline
9 & 10\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Is that possible using `knitr` and `kableExtra`?

I can use a workaround. For example, use chunk options `results='asis'`, and in the chunk, do

```r
cat("\\begin{center}",sep='\n')

knitr::kable(head(cars),
             format = 'latex')

cat("\\end{center}",sep='\n')
```

However, I would like to know if this it is possible without the workaround and whether I am missing something.

## Minimal reproducible example

The following is a minimal working example of an RMarkdown document at produces the three kinds of tables mentioned above. Dependencies are `magrittr`, `knitr`, and `kableExtra`.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(magrittr)
```

This produces a `tabular`, non-floating, table. But it is not centered.
```{r}
knitr::kable(head(cars), format = 'latex')
```

The following code produces a centered table, but using a `table` environment, so it floats (in this case to the top of the page), which is probably what we usually want, but we don't *always* want.
```{r}
knitr::kable(head(PlantGrowth), format = 'latex') %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

We can produce a centered `tabular` environment using chunk option `results='asis'` etc.
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat("\\begin{center}",sep='\n')

knitr::kable(head(ToothGrowth),
             format = 'latex')

cat("\\end{center}",sep='\n')
```
````

Rendering this (as a `pdf_document`) creates a single page pdf with this content:
[image]

Comment: Can you make a [mre] including a rmarkdown header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the `table.envir` argument to `"center"` to wrap the `\tabular` in `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`.  In your MRE:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(magrittr)
```

This produces a `tabular`, non-floating, table, and it *is* centered:
```{r}
knitr::kable(head(cars), format = 'latex', table.envir = "center")
```
````

If you want to wrap it twice (e.g. centered and boldface), you can use something like `table.envir = c("bf", "center", "bf")`: because `kable()` isn't smart enough to reverse the order when adding the `\end{}` markers, you need to use a palindrome.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\centering`, you'll avoid the extra vertical spacing from the `center` environment:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \AddToHook{env/tabular/before}{\begingroup\centering}
  - \AddToHook{env/tabular/after}{\par\endgroup}
---

```{r}
library(magrittr)
```

text



```{r}
knitr::kable(head(cars), format = 'latex')
```

text
````

[image]

Comment: Your `knitr::kable` code, by using `kable_styling`, produces a `table` environment, which is what I don't want. If we leave out the `kable_styling`, we will have a non-floating table. And we could/should use `\centering` instead of `begin{center}`. But ultimately, it seems we have to add in our own LaTeX, either as you did, or as I did with `cat` in the chunk. That's fine with me. Ultimately, I wanted to know if we could have a centered `tabular` by using `kable`. I believe the answer is no.

Comment: The stuff in the code chunk does not matter, replace it with something that does not use a float. I'm patching the tabular environment and not the table environment to be independent of the float